Snyk delta throw Snyk CLI, behavior, report to platform azure DevOps, how can I break the pipeline?
I am using Snyk delta trying to detect only new vulneravilities,
I ran the next pipeline
- script: |
    npm install -g snyk snyk-delta
    snyk auth $(SNYK_TOKEN) 
    snyk test --json --print-deps | snyk-delta --baselineOrg xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx- --baselineProject xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
    snyk monitor    
  displayName: 'Ejecutar Snyk delta Test'

I had to use Snyk monitor or it won't sent the report to Snyk platform
When I run the project once, I am getting this result
Paths
   bcrypt@4.2.1 no issue:
     paramiko@3.4.0=>bcrypt@4.2.1
   pycparser@2.22 no issue:
     paramiko@3.4.0=>cryptography@44.0.0=>cffi@1.17.1=>pycparser@2.22
       paramiko@3.4.0=>pynacl@1.5.0=>cffi@1.17.1=>pycparser@2.22
   cffi@1.17.1 no issue:
     paramiko@3.4.0=>cryptography@44.0.0=>cffi@1.17.1
       paramiko@3.4.0=>pynacl@1.5.0=>cffi@1.17.1
   cryptography@44.0.0 no issue:
     paramiko@3.4.0=>cryptography@44.0.0
   pynacl@1.5.0 no issue:
     paramiko@3.4.0=>pynacl@1.5.0
   urllib3@1.24.3 no issue:
     requests@2.20.0=>urllib3@1.24.3
===============
Removed 1
 [ 'urllib3@1.23' ]
_____________________________

New issue introduced !
License Issue:

  1/1: LGPL-3.0 license [Low Severity]
    Via: paramiko@3.4.0 

Whitout do changes, I ran the pipeline again and get the next result
_____________________________
Direct deps:
Added 0 

===============
Removed 0

##################
Indirect deps:
Added 0 

===============
Paths
===============
Removed 0
 []
_____________________________
No new issues found !

Monitoring /home/vsts/work/1/s (s)...

I read the documentation but I dont know how is the exactly behavior of Snyk delta.
I added a new library with vulnerabilities, the test show me it but none of the cases breaks the pipeline.
_____________________________

New issues introduced !
Security Vulnerabilities:
  1/5: SNYK-PYTHON-LXML-2316995:Cross-site Scripting (XSS) [Low Severity][cvssScore: 8.2]
    Via: lxml@4.6.3
    Fixed in: lxml 4.6.5


  2/5: SNYK-PYTHON-LXML-2940874:NULL Pointer Dereference [Medium Severity][cvssScore: 5.3]
    Via: lxml@4.6.3
    Fixed in: lxml 4.9.1


  3/5: SNYK-PYTHON-PARAMIKO-2429583:Race Condition [Low Severity][cvssScore: 6.3]
    Via: paramiko@2.1.0
    Fixed in: paramiko 2.10.1


  4/5: SNYK-PYTHON-PARAMIKO-42086:Authentication Bypass [Low Severity][cvssScore: 9.8]
    Via: paramiko@2.1.0
    Fixed in: paramiko 1.17.6, 1.18.5, 2.0.8, 2.1.5, 2.2.3, 2.3.2, 2.4.1


  5/5: SNYK-PYTHON-PARAMIKO-6130887:Authentication Bypass by Capture-replay [Medium Severity][cvssScore: 5.9]
    Via: paramiko@2.1.0
    Fixed in: paramiko 3.4.0



Monitoring /home/vsts/work/1/s (s)...

Does anyone can tell me how it suppouse to be. cus it dont breaks the pipeline.
And other question if i run the pipeline, the project in Snykk platform goes to be updated. so the baseline is going to be updated with the last scan. so how shuold it be used ? cus Snyk delta just give me the option to usa project ID no SCan iD (or some like that)
How I think should be the flow.

No vulnerabilities in the project --> success pipeline --> add to platform
I add new library with known vunerabilities --> break pipe --> add to platform (now use this new scan as baseline)
I add  other new library with known vunerabilities --> break pipe (show oly new vulnerabilities and not those of 2 step) --> add to platform (now use this new scan as baseline)

Am I right?
I will appreciate any response. thanks.
